# Updating first record of a group of records t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUserLink](
    [IDUserLink] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IDUser] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDRegie] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DefaultAgency] [bit] NULL
)
```

I'm looking for a query /script to update the field DefaultAgency. I'd like to set it to 1 for the first record that comes for each group of record with a same IDUser.

example :

```
IDUserLink IDUser IDRegie DefaultAgency (Goal)
1          1      1       null           DefaultAgency to be set to 1
2          1      2       null
3          1      3       null
4          2      2       null           DefaultAgency to be set to 1
5          2      1       null     
6          3      1       null           DefaultAgency to be set to 1
 ...etc
```

Can I achieve this using a simple sql query or should I script it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
update tblUserLink
set DefaultAgency = 1
where IDUserLink in
(select min(IDUserLink) from tblUserLink group by IDUser)
```

Comment: Although this statement works it might be better (performance wise) to use the "exists" functionality.

Answer (score 7):

If you're on SQL Server 2005+, you can use a common table expression:

```
with cte as (
   select *,
      row_number() over (partition by IDUser order by IDUserLink) as [rn]
   from tblUserLink
)
update c
set DefaultAgency = 1
from cte as c
where c.rn = 1
```